# Networking: 4 Separate Subnets Default Route Consistency Warning?

Tags: networking, server, netplan, router, systemd-networkd

Just installed Ubuntu and one of my network card ports does not work and has no ping to it's IP - eno2.

Netplan as configured during install:

```
    # This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 11.22.33.210/24
      - 1a2a:3a4a:5a6a:16::601/64
      gateway4: 11.22.33.1
      gateway6: 1a2a:3a4a:5a6a:16::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 1.0.0.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        - 2606:4700:4700::1111
        - 2606:4700:4700::1001
        - 2001:4860:4860::8888
        - 2001:4860:4860::8844
      accept-ra: no
    eno2:
      addresses:
      - 22.33.44.210/24
      - 1a2a:3a4a:5a6a:17::602/64
      gateway4: 22.33.44.1
      gateway6: 1a2a:3a4a:5a6a:17::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 1.0.0.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        - 2606:4700:4700::1111
        - 2606:4700:4700::1001
        - 2001:4860:4860::8888
        - 2001:4860:4860::8844
      accept-ra: no
    eno3:
  addresses:
  - 33.44.55.210/24
  - 1a2a:3a4a:5a6a:18::603/64
  gateway4: 33.44.55.1
  gateway6: 1a2a:3a4a:5a6a:18::1
  nameservers:
    addresses:
    - 1.1.1.1
    - 1.0.0.1
    - 8.8.8.8
    - 8.8.4.4
    - 2606:4700:4700::1111
    - 2606:4700:4700::1001
    - 2001:4860:4860::8888
    - 2001:4860:4860::8844
    - 2606:4700:4700::1111
    - 2606:4700:4700::1001
    - 2001:4860:4860::8888
    - 2001:4860:4860::8844
  accept-ra: no
eno4:
  addresses:
  - 44.55.66.210/24
  - 1a2a:3a4a:5a6a:19::604/64
  gateway4: 44.55.66.1
  gateway6: 1a2a:3a4a:5a6a:19::1
  nameservers:
    addresses:
    - 1.1.1.1
    - 1.0.0.1
    - 8.8.8.8
    - 8.8.4.4
    - 2606:4700:4700::1111
    - 2606:4700:4700::1001
    - 2001:4860:4860::8888
    - 2001:4860:4860::8844
  accept-ra: no
  version: 2
```

Ran this

```
echo 101 eno1-route >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo 102 eno2-route >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo 103 eno3-route >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo 104 eno4-route >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

rc.local

```
#!/bin/bash 

# Increasing The Transmit Queue Length
/sbin/ifconfig eno1 txqueuelen 10000
/sbin/ifconfig eno2 txqueuelen 10000
/sbin/ifconfig eno3 txqueuelen 10000
/sbin/ifconfig eno4 txqueuelen 10000
/sbin/ifconfig lo txqueuelen 10000
#routes
ip route add default via 11.22.33.1 dev eno1 table eno1-route
ip rule add from 11.22.33.210 lookup eno1-route
ip route add default via 22.33.44.1 dev eno2 table eno2-route
ip rule add from 22.33.44.210 lookup eno2-route
ip route add default via 33.44.55.1 dev eno3 table eno3-route
ip rule add from 33.44.55.210 lookup eno3-route
ip route add default via 44.55.66.1 dev eno4 table eno4-route
ip rule add from 44.55.66.77 lookup eno4-route
```

Getting this error when applying netplan.

```
** (generate:5742): WARNING **: 05:13:22.079: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in eno2 but also in eno4
```

All IPs both IPv4 and IPv6 seem pinglable after reboot. What is going on? I already have different routing tables. Conflicting default route declarations!?

`ip route list` returns

```
default via 22.33.44.1 dev eno2 proto static 
default via 33.44.55.1 dev eno3 proto static 
default via 11.22.33.1 dev eno1 proto static 
default via 44.55.66.1 dev eno4 proto static 
44.55.66.0/24 dev eno4 proto kernel scope link src 44.55.66.210 
11.22.33.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 11.22.33.210 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
22.33.44.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 22.33.44.210 
33.44.55.0/24 dev eno3 proto kernel scope link src 33.44.55.210
```

Answer (score 1):

You *have* different routing tables, but when you use the `gateway4` and `gateway6` shorthand, this does not make use of those routing tables.  To get the results you want, you will need to spell out the default routes as `routes:` instead as described at https://netplan.io/reference/#default-routes.

Comment: Tried. Returns Invalid YAML: mapping values are not allowed in this context:
            routes:
                  ^

Comment: Updated the answer with a pointer to complete documentation of `routes:`, including use of routing tables for multiple default routes.

Comment: If the routes and rules are not added like described in rc.local above, there is no ping to the IPs, so I take it they are in use. Thanks for the update, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"Getting this error when applying netplan.

** (generate:5742): WARNING **: 05:13:22.079: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in eno2 but also in eno4"

Check the /etc/netplan folder for more than one YAML configuration file.

If more than one file, clean out for a single file may cure the conflict.

I was having this error message, and discovered a 99- netplan file was conflicting with the standard 00-installer-config.yaml file.

Deleting the 99 file cured the problem.